# Peak points of sequences

Tags: calculus, analysis, discrete-mathematics

[image of question in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Y7v.jpg)
[image]

I am not sure how the fraction multiplied to the sequence (alpha_n) will affect the peak points, and do I approach the question by doing a case by case analysis where I assume n as 3k, 3k-1 and 3k-2 respectively? Many thanks.

Comment: It might be worth calculating the first ten or so terms of $a_n$ and $b_n$ to see what is happening.  You might also tell us how *peak point* is defined (local/global, signed/absolute)

Comment: a_n is a peak point of (a_n) if a_n >=a_k for all k>n. I am not sure if i am comprehending this question correctly, but are there 3 subsequences of alpha_n which are the remainder of n when divided by 3? How do I find all the peak points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the sequence $a_n$ for $n>0$ we see
\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha &=& \,\,-1,\,0,\,1,\,\,-1,\,0,\,1,\,\,-1,\,0,\,1,\qquad-1,\,\,\,0,\,\,\,1,\cdots\\
\left\{\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right\}&=&\phantom{-}\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4},\phantom{-}\frac{4}{5},\frac{5}{6},\frac{6}{7},\phantom{-}\frac{7}{8},\frac{8}{9},\frac{9}{10},\phantom{-}\frac{10}{11},\frac{11}{12},\frac{12}{13},\cdots\\
a_n&=&-\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{3}{4},\,-\frac{4}{5},0,\frac{6}{7},\,-\frac{7}{8},0,\frac{9}{10},\,-\frac{10}{11},0,\frac{12}{13},\cdots
\end{eqnarray}
So we see that the positive terms form an increasing sequence, thus there are no peak points.

On the other hand, looking at the sequence for $b_n$ we see
\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha &=& \,\,-1,\,0,\,1,\,\,-1,\,0,\,1,\,\,-1,\,0,\,1,\qquad-1,\,\,\,0,\,\,\,1,\cdots\\
\left\{\dfrac{n+1}{n}\right\}
&=&\phantom{-}\frac{2}{1},\frac{3}{2},\frac{4}{3},\phantom{-}\frac{5}{4},\frac{6}{5},\frac{7}{6},\phantom{-}\frac{8}{7},\frac{9}{8},\frac{10}{9},\phantom{-}\frac{11}{10},\frac{12}{11},\frac{13}{12},\cdots\\
b_n&=&-\frac{2}{1},0,\frac{4}{3},\,-\frac{5}{4},0,\frac{7}{6},\,-\frac{8}{7},0,\frac{10}{9},\,-\frac{11}{10},0,\frac{13}{12},\cdots
\end{eqnarray}

The positive terms form a decreasing sequence $\left\{\frac{3n+1}{3n}\right\}$ of peak points.